# How can I use a mask to find files with the same names in Explorer?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

What I would like to do is to use Explorer to locate all the files with the same names in a given folder and all of its sub-folders.

Example...

```
C:\Photos\20070113\20070113065.jpg
C:\Photos\20070110\20070113065.jpg
C:\Photos\20070108\20070113065.jpg
```

As you can see from this example, my problem is that I have the same JPEG files with the same names in more than one sub-folder. For some reason they have been misplaced in the wrong folders (dates don't match with the folders). I have some 2800 JPEG files in this root. But only maybe 10% are duplicates.

Is there some kind of mask I can use in the search field in Explorer so that it only shows me files that have the same name?

Something like `*.jpg [same file name]`?

Answer (score 2):

You can search from a CMD window with the following commands:

```
cd \
dir /s filename.jpg
```

This will search all subdirs in drive C: for 'filename.jpg'

Comment: Note that this will only scan for one duplicate name at a time. Not very useful when there's a large number of potential candidates.